# Get matching values from dictionaries in a list then add and average

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to get matching *values* of the "week" key from a list of dictionaries. Ultimately what I want to do is take all the week 1's add up the "efficiency" for the week and find the average, then the same for week 2 and so forth.

Note: actual data set is much larger

```
data = [{"day": 1/2/2015, "efficiency": 35, "week": 1}, 
        {"day": 1/3/2015, "efficiency": 37, "week": 1}, 
        {"day": 1/4/2015, "efficiency": 48, "week": 2},
        {"day": 1/5/2015, "efficiency": 44, "week": 2}, 
       ]
```

I could do this with something like:

```
count = 0
stop_point = len(data)
week_total = []
previous_week = False
avg_per_week = []

for item in data:
    if previous_week == False or previous_week == item['week'] and count != stop_point:
        week_total.append(item['efficiency'])
        previous_week = item['week']
        count += 1
    else:
         total = 0
         for item in week_total:
             total += item
         if count == stop_point:
            previous_week = item['week']
         avrg_efficiency = total / len(week_total)
         avg_per_week.append({"week": previous_week, "average": avrg_efficiency})
         week_total = []
         count += 1
         previous_week = item['week']
```

But I am thinking there has to be a DRY'er way to do this. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a mapping between a week and it's items usinf [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

week_to_items = defaultdict(list)
for item in data:
    week_to_items[item['week']].append(item)
```

Now do whatever you want using the mapping, which is easier:

```
for week, week_items in week_to_items.iteritems():
    efficiency_average = float(sum(map(lambda x: x['efficiency'], week_items))) / len(week_items)
    print week, efficiency_average
```

Answer (score 1):

What about simply:

```
for week in set(elem['week'] for elem in data):
    matches = filter(None, (elem['efficiency'] if elem['week'] == week else None for elem in data))
    total = sum(matches)
    avg   = total / float(len(matches))
    print "Week=%d  Total=%d  Average=%s" % (week, total, avg)
```

Which outputs

```
Week=1  Total=72  Average=36.0
Week=2  Total=92  Average=46.0
```